# Making a large file using the terminal

Tags: command-line, files, ram

I want to make a file that is very large in size for testing purposes that should contains unique words (strictly not repeated). It can in GB, TB, etc. May I do this with the terminal?

I am using [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the conversation that was taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48030/discussion-on-question-by-avani-badheka-making-a-large-file-using-the-terminal).

Comment: Define what you mean by word? An English word? Or is 'k345j#_' a word for you as well?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Creating an infinite number of words, guaranteed unique

The script below will generate guaranteed unique words from characters from the alphabet. The issue with any fixed length of characters is that it will produce a *limited* set of possibilities, limiting the size of your file.

I therefore used `python`'s `permutations`, which produces a (finite) number of unique words. *However* After using all the combinations, we simply start over, printing the words 2, then 3, four, `n` times etc., every value for `n` will create a new unique word. Thus we have a generator to produce 100% certainly unique words.

#### The script:

```py
import itertools
import string

ab = [c for c in string.ascii_lowercase]

t = 1
while True:   
    for n in range(1, len(ab)+1): 
        words = itertools.permutations(ab, n)
        for word in words:
            print(t*("".join(word)))
    t += 1
```

#### How to use

- Simply copy the script into an empty file, save it as `unique_generator.py`
- Run it by the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/unique_generator.py > /path/to/bigfile.txt
  ```

#### Note

The script produces unique words of various lenght. If you want, start- or max length can be set, by changing the lines:

```
for n in range(1, len(ab)+1)
```

(replace the start of the range), and changing:

```
while True:
```

into (for example):

```
while t < 10:
```

In the last case, the length of the words is max 10 times the alphabet.

#### Ending the process

- When running it from terminal, simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- Otherwise:

  ```
  kill $(pgrep -f /path/to/unique_generator.py)
  ```

  should do the job.

Comment: Very nice ! I've used permutations once. Quite a useful tool

Comment: @Serg I *love* itertools :) Th loop thing is stuborn btw, still trying... permissions are fine.

Comment: while running "python3 /path/to/unique_generator.py > /path/to/bigfile.txt " command how to stop it  when we don't want further .

Comment: @JacobVlijm : thank you for your kind effort . how to stop command "python3 /path/to/unique_generator.py > /path/to/bigfile.txt " when we reached at desired size ?

Comment: Hi, @Avanibadheka edited my answer to include stopping the process.

Comment: accepted :) good explanation .

Comment: @Avanibadheka Thanks! hope it will be useful :)

Comment: Wouldn't returning the words instead of printing them be more favourable? The result can be piped into the file.

Comment: @Mast That is also possible of course, not sure if one is better then the other, this is the result of how I wrote it (writing > testing). The advantage of this way is that it is more familiar with how people are used to use the terminal. They can first see what it does by not using the `>` section.

Answer (score 6):

Simplest one-liner to make random lines of characters:

```
while true; do echo $RANDOM | base64 >> BIGFILE.txt  ; done
```

or alternatively:

```
while true; do echo $RANDOM | sha512sum  >> BIGFILE.txt ; done
```

For better uniqueness , you can use `/dev/urandom`:

```
cat /dev/urandom | base64
```

Terminate the command with Ctrl+C, when your file reaches desired size

Consider also [random string/password generators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/230674/85039) :

Thus,one of the answers there, can be adapted to have this:

```
while true; do openssl rand -base64 20 ; done
```

In case you don't want to use punctuation characters and numbers, but use only letters, then we can use `tr` to correct that:

```
while true; do openssl rand -base64 20 | tr -d '[[:digit:]][[:punct:]]'  ; done
```

For extra randomness, you can shuffle the characters of generated strings using `shuf`.

```
while true; do openssl rand -base64 20 | fold -w1 | shuf | tr -d '\n' ; done
```

And so on and so forth. You could even pass the output to another set of `base64` or `sha256sum` commands to make them even more random.

For those who like alternative languages other than shell, here's a python  one-liner:

```
python -c $'import string,random;i = [i for i in string.uppercase + string.lowercase + string.digits];\nwhile not random.shuffle(i): print "".join(i)'
```

Comment: yes , it can generate problem . It can be random so no guarantee for unique words.

Comment: I've addressed the uniqueness problems from several angles already, guys, so consider removing the comments

Comment: Technically it's still possible for something to be not unique, but it's pretty unlikely

Comment: @DonyorM  if you're pointing at the example with `$RANDOM` variable, then yes, but `/dev/urandom` is quite low in random probability, especially in combination with shasum.

Comment: "quite low in random probability" . . . em,my sleep deprived brain means that there's low probability to have non-unique data generated. But you get the idea

Comment: @Serg : for your last python one-liner , how this will stop ? I am in learning phase in python that's why asking u.

Comment: @Avanibadheka  Same idea - use Ctrl+C to stop it when you're happy with file size. I mean, it's possible to write a whole script that checks file size and breaks out of while loop, but . . . why complicate things ? :)  Whenever I test something with large files, i just let while loop run until I see in file manager that the file size is big enough, or use `du` command from terminal

Comment: yes , it is going to happen.upvoted for python line.

Comment: My answer was downvoted. Can somebody explain why ?

Comment: I don't think it was. Someone undid an upvote (wasn't me).

Answer (score 6):

To get a large file full on random words use the following command:

```
cat /dev/urandom | head -c 1000000 | tr -dc "A-Za-z0-9\n" | sort | uniq
```

This will create a file with a unqiue word on each line and strings of random text. You can increase the size of the file by make 1000 larger or smaller. Each count is equal to roughly one byte.

To make the words space seperated, simply pass them back through `tr "\n" " "`.

```
cat /dev/urandom | head -c 1000000 | tr -dc "A-Za-z0-9\n" | sort | uniq | tr "\n" " "
```

This also avoids the performance problems associated with loops on the shell.

Comment: what are the *performance problems with loops on the shell*? I hope this is not off-topic

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga: short answer: spawning new processes is expensive. Loops like in Serg's answer do so in each iteration, potentially mutliple times. This answer reuses the same processes to do all work. For longer answer, please submit a site question ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If a limited alphabet and very predictable output are fine, the following is probably the fastest (and most golfed :P) answer:

```
seq 100
```

(if words may consist of just numbers), or:

```
seq 100 | tr 0-9 A-I
```

(if there is a desire to use actual letters).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `/proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid` in Linux to generate [UUIDs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122.html), which should be guaranteed to be unique:

```
[~]$ for i in {1..10}; do cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid; done
c8072c40-32f5-4f14-8794-c3ab68e1a0f5
2f2630d8-0e17-4cba-8e62-586ee23f0ebb
97606886-f227-46f6-827a-141b0db57c59
5ffea57c-c3bf-4ba6-8c08-8a1b29ee8f6c
2b90f797-2def-4433-ae71-6f404db944fc
fcb793e9-6102-472d-a7a0-7bf5204dbee5
d84e2877-6804-4bed-85f0-0a551234425a
3d9445ca-335c-4960-83d5-6cb1bef8b9eb
913bce71-5c20-47f7-a22e-277be6856a57
8f232541-f8c1-46ba-b57a-0d11314c3483
```

You can remove - character with `tr -d` and then redirect this to a file:

```
[~]$ for i in {1..10000}; do cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid | tr -d '-' ; done > /tmp/words
[~]$ sort /tmp/words | uniq | wc -l
10000
```